# how to store a value permanently in android?

Tags: java, android, key-value-store

I am trying to make an initial synchronisation type of task. That is, the method can only be executed once when app is installed and not again. So I want to store a value called which has default value 0 but when sync method is called it becomes 1.
Storing the variable on sd card is what I found but I think it is too much for storing one integer variable 
Any suggestion on how to do it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are multiple ways to store the values permanently in Android application. But the best solution in your case is SharedPreference.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

You can store the values in all primitive types.

This data only gets removed if you uninstall the app or Clear data of your app from Settings.

Answer (score 3):

use SharePreference

```
    // save data into share SharePreference
    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("FILE_NAME", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = sp.edit();
    edit.putInt("key",value);
    edit.apply();

    // get data from share SharePreference
    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("FILE_NAME", MODE_PRIVATE);
    int result = sp.getInt("key", -1);
```